# Render partial in rails controller called using ajax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, render

I have rails application where I have part of views as partials and I re-factored couple of views as SPA. I have problem with one functionality. In one place I was rendering partial without calling controller like following:

```
def create
      school_service.update_preview
      @user = get_user
      @result = prepare_result

      render 'school/result/show', locals: {
        pupil:       @user,
        result:      @result
      }
end
```

I was calling this method using form. Now I call this from JS using AJAX. Is it possible to render that view in the same way? I wouldn't like to rewrite  'school/result/show' to SPA. Thanks for all answers.

Comment: What's SPA if you don't mind me asking?

Comment: You're missing a `partial:`.

Comment: SPA - single page app

Comment: @user2239655 you just want to render that partial from your ajax?

Comment: I don't thing if it is possible. I need to set pupil and result variables and I can do this only on server side.

Comment: @user2239655 if you are doing it by ajax then you can render it in your create.js.erb file

Comment: I don't know that solution can you give me some examples. Maybe similar questions because I didn't find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question says `I was calling this method using form. Now I call this using AJAX. Is it possible to render that view in the same way?`

Since you are using AJAX i assume you'll have something remote: true in your form something like:

```
<%= form_for(@user, remote: true) do |f| %>
  # your fields
<% end %>
```

This will take you to the **create action** in your controller and you can have a **respond_to block** in your controller *to handle your js format*

```
def create
  @user = get_user
  @result = prepare_result
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js {}
  end
end
```

This will allow you to have **create.js.erb** file in your views where you can write your js to render your partial

```
$(".your_parent_element_class").html("<%=j render partial: "school/result/show",locals:{pupil: @user, result: @result} %>")
```

For more details checkout [**`working with javascript in rails`**](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#a-simple-example)